# Get multiple items from XML with SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, foreach, simplexml

I'm trying to loop multiple items from an XML with the code below.

```
$xml = get_data('the-url');
$data = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach($data->item AS $item) {
    foreach($item AS $test) {
        var_dump($test);
    }
}
```

The XML looks like this:

```
<xml>
    <item>
        <name>...</name>
        <chapter>...</chapter>
        <text>
            ...
        </text>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>...</name>
        <chapter>...</chapter>
        <text>
            ...
        </text>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>...</name>
        <chapter>...</chapter>
        <text>
            ...
        </text>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>...</name>
        <chapter>...</chapter>
        <text>
            ...
        </text>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>...</name>
        <chapter>...</chapter>
        <text>
            ...
        </text>
    </item>
</xml>
```

As it is right now, the `var_dump($test)` prints this:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (0) { } object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (0) { }
object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (0) { } object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (0) { }
object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (0) { } object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (0) { }
object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (0) { } object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (0) { }
object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (0) { } object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (0) { }
object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (0) { } object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (0) { }
object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (0) { } object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (0) { } ...
```

What should I do to make my code to loop all the items and prints the value?

Comment: Your current output is not very readable. Wrap the `var_dump()` in `<pre>` tags to get a prettier output.

Comment: @AmalMurali The output was in one straight line but I edited it :)

Comment: [This](http://pastie.org/8927403) is how I meant it. Okay. What is the output you're trying to produce?

Comment: @AmalMurali Aha. But the output only prints those lines over and over again. I want to loop all the items and get the value from each item.

Comment: I was only showing how to get prettier output with `var_dump()`, not how to solve your actual issue.

Comment: @AmalMurali I know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$xml_content = file_get_contents('http://url/feed.xml');
$data = simplexml_load_string($xml_content);

foreach ($data->item as $item) {
    var_dump($item->bookname);
}
```

You can also cast whole $item to array if you need:

```
foreach ($data->item as $item) {
    $itemArray = (array) $item;
    var_dump($itemArray);
}
```

You were dumping objects, when you need to cast the to string first to return the text value.
Also, I do not think the second `foreach` was doing anything or needed, so I removed it.

Comment: Thanks but I got this error message: `Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity ...`. I tried with my own function `get_data()` and after that with `file_get_contents()` as you used before your last edit. I'm trying to load this XML and get the values: http://labs.bible.org/api/?passage=Leviticus%2024&type=xml

Comment: answer updated; `simplexml_load_file()` is only for local files it seems

Comment: `var_dump($item->toString());` gives me `Fatal error: Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::toString() in ...` while `var_dump((string)$item);` gives me `string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" ...`

Comment: Same result as before: `string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) ""`. I copy-pasted your code

Comment: check it out now, I have tested it on my own environment now, and it works.