# Display xml file cascaded contents in a drop down via php

Tags: php, xml-parsing, dropdownbox, cascadingdropdown, php-parser

I have a local xml file which I am trying to display over a webpage with following code.

All I get is a blank page.

```php
<?php
   $xml_content = file_get_contents("C:\Users\user\Downloads\93D7.xml");
   $data = simplexml_load_string($xml_content);
   foreach ($data->item as $item) {
      var_dump($item->bookname);
   }
?>
```

Once the display works, I want to have a drop down where I will select the xml element / entity and it will display the value or child of that element / entity.

Can someone help?

I referred : [Get multiple items from XML with SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22427043/get-multiple-items-from-xml-with-simplexml) &
[populating dropdown with values from xml file in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353303/populating-dropdown-with-values-from-xml-file-in-php)

Both individually gives me a blank page.

Comment: are you running the code with `display_errors = on` ? You should refer to this to see how you can find possible issues in your code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: Yes, display_errors=on in php.ini.

Comment: Do a var_dump or similar of the $xml_content right after you load the contents to see if it returns the content and then post the result please

Comment: Good idea. Let me try that and get back to you. Though it loads fine on browser.

Comment: Hi Cornel.Raiu, vardump just after loading works fine. It outputs the xml content, though with some different formatting. Like this:

Comment: Hi Cornel.Raiu, vardump just after loading works fine. It outputs the xml content, though with some different formatting. With => deliminator in between elements. It is a huge file and therefore can not post the content here.

Comment: and what do you get in `var_dump($data)`?

Comment: These are the first few lines. Rest of the code looks the same.        object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (15) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(4) "User" } ["overview"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (11) { ["permission"]=> string(4) "Full " ["LoginID"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#16 (0) { } ["User creation"]=> string(21) "06:07:2016 - 00:01:46"